# c++ 17 filesystem copy_file access denied

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17

I'm using visual studio 2017, running with the c++17 ISO Standard(not boost) set to be able to use `<filesystem>`. I'm running into a wall though because everytime I run, whether in debug or release, `file_copy()` gives me the error access denied. I've checked the other bits of my code and the only thing that isn't working is `file_copy()`. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error and how to fix it? I'm the administrative account on my PC.

```
std::vector<std::string> findAndCopyFiles()
{
    std::vector<std::string> fileNames;
    std::error_code errCode;
    errCode.clear();

    fs::current_path("C:\\Users\\kenny\\Desktop\\Engine", errCode);
    std::cout << errCode.message() << std::endl; errCode.clear();

    fs::path pa = fs::current_path();
    pa += "\\TEMP";
    std::cout << pa.string() << std::endl;

    if (fs::create_directory(pa, errCode))//Create directory for copying all files)
    {
        std::cout << "Directory created successfully" << std::endl;
        std::cout << errCode.message() << std::endl; errCode.clear();
    }
    fs::path tempDir(pa);
    fs::path currentDirectory = fs::current_path();
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator dirIter(currentDirectory);
    for (auto &p : dirIter)
    {
        if (p.path().extension() == ".cpp" || p.path().extension() == ".h")
        {
            //std::string fileContents = getFileContents(p.path().string());

            std::string fileName = p.path().stem().string();
            if (!fs::copy_file(p.path(), tempDir, fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing, errCode))
            {
                std::cout << "failed to copy file: " << fileName << " from " << p.path().string() << " to " << tempDir.string() <<std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << errCode.message() << std::endl; errCode.clear();

            //ensures file is a cpp file before adding it to list of fileNames
            if (p.path().extension().string() == ".cpp")
            {
                auto it = std::find(fileNames.begin(), fileNames.end(), fileName); //seaches TEMP folder for file
                if (it == fileNames.end())
                {//if file was not found in vector of registered file names, add it
                    fileNames.push_back(fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "All files found. " << fileNames.size() << " files were found" << std::endl;
    return fileNames;
}
```

Comment: Next time please add the code to the question. Remember that a question on StackOverflow is supposed to help readers years from now. Links will rot making the question pointless. I just selected the code from the link and used the {} button to add it as a code block.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, I just don't know a good way to actually make it into a block of code like that. I'm still pretty knew on this site

Comment: Its probably one reason why your question has a negative rating.

Comment: I'm slightly confused but... aren't you trying to overwrite a directory with a regular file?  Sorry if I've missed something.

Comment: G.M you're entirely right, I was under the assumption that it would copy the file into the directory but now I've realized that you have to specify the name of the new file as it will be created and then the file will be copied into the new one. edit: Feel free to post it as the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the comments.  You were trying to overwrite a directory with a regular file.  From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file) [trimmed]

```
o Otherwise, if the destination file already exists...
  o Report an error if any of the following is true:
    o to and from are the same as determined by equivalent(from, to);
    o to is not a regular file as determined by !is_regular_file(to)
```

So you need to append the filename to the destination directory path using the [`std::filesystem::operator/](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_slash) overload (untested)...

```
if (!fs::copy_file(p.path(), tempDir / p.filename(), fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing, errCode))
```